# Displaying pictures in html

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I am learning about the DOM and incorporating Javascript in html files, I have tried this code that display and hide pictures using the event listener `click`. however, pictures don't seem to appear even no error is detected in the Chrome console.

NOTE: I only posted the concerned code, I omitted some of the HTML tags

```html
<style>

.hide{
    display: none;
}

</style>


<main>
<ul>
    <li><a data-img="face" id="facebook" href="#"> Facebook </a></li>

    <li><a data-img="insta" id="instagram" href="#"> Instagarm </a></li>

    <li><a data-img="snap" id="snapchat" href="#"> Snapchat </a></li>
    
</ul>

<img class="hide" id="face" scr="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/facebook_square-128.png">

<img class="hide" id="insta" scr="http://bikecleanse.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Insta-Logo.png" >

<img class="hide" id="snap" scr="https://icon-icons.com/icons2/686/PNG/512/snapchat_snap_chat_icon_logo_social_app_red_icon-icons.com_61225.png">

</main>

<script type="text/javascript">
    
var face = document.getElementById('facebook');
var insta = document.getElementById('instagram');
var snap = document.getElementById('snapchat');

face.addEventListener("click", show);
insta.addEventListener("click", show);
snap.addEventListener("click", show);

function show() {

    var picId = this.attributes["data-img"].value;
    var pic = document.getElementById(picId);
     
    if(pic.className === "hide"){
        pic.className="";
    } else {
        pic.className= "hide";
    }
     
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you issues is that it is `src` and not `scr`, so change that attribute and the images will show.

Second, I would recommend using [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) with `add`, `remove` and `contains`. You could also use `toggle` to make your code even smaller like so:

```html
<style>
  .hide {
    display: none;
  }
</style>


<main>
  <ul>
    <li> <a data-img="face" id="facebook" href="#"> Facebook </a> </li>

    <li> <a data-img="insta" id="instagram" href="#"> Instagarm </a> </li>

    <li> <a data-img="snap" id="snapchat" href="#"> Snapchat </a> </li>

  </ul>

  <img class="hide" id="face" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/facebook_square-128.png">


  <img class="hide" id="insta" src="http://bikecleanse.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Insta-Logo.png">

  <img class="hide" id="snap" src="https://icon-icons.com/icons2/686/PNG/512/snapchat_snap_chat_icon_logo_social_app_red_icon-icons.com_61225.png">

</main>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var face = document.getElementById('facebook');
  var insta = document.getElementById('instagram');
  var snap = document.getElementById('snapchat');

  face.addEventListener("click", show);
  insta.addEventListener("click", show);
  snap.addEventListener("click", show);

  function show() {
    var picId = this.attributes["data-img"].value;
    var pic = document.getElementById(picId);
    pic.classList.toggle('hide', !pic.classList.contains('hide'))
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the `event` input to your `show` function. I modified your show function like below. Check if this works for you:

```
function show(e) {

    let picId = e.target.dataset.img;

    let pic = document.getElementById(picId);

    if(pic.classList.contains('hide'){
        pic.classList.remove('hide');
    }
    else{
        pic.classList.add('hide');
    }
}
```